# ListPreference in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, listpreference

I want to show a ListPreference inside a Fragment.
The ListPreference is the same as used in a standalone settings Activity. But I can't figure out how to directly open the ListPreference view from the fragment (without showing the whole Settings view).
I found there exists a class DialogFragment, but does it work for that use case?
Note that I'm using the compatibility version of Fragment API. The class PreferenceFragment is not available there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I can't figure out how to directly open the ListPreference view from the fragment (without showing the whole Settings view).

AFAIK, this is not supported on any version of Android.